# Extension of Menage Problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have been looking at the Menage Problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9nage_problem), and am trying to generalize it to count the number of permutations $\sigma \in S_n$ in which for all $i \in \{1,2,3...,n \}$, $\sigma(i) \not \in \{ i - 1, i, i + 1 \}$.

I am working under the assumption that $1$ and $n$ are adjacent (i.e. the points are situated on a circle) and was wondering how I could solve this problem. I have been tried a couple of things (recursion, inclusion-exclusion) but haven't come up with much.

Comment: Indeed, this is equivalent to calculating the permenant as Robert says in his answer. To actually *calculate* that I recommend using the method of rook polynomials. This *exact problem* is given in Riordan's "Introduction to Combinatorial Analysis", Chapter 8, problem 24. There is no answer section, but chapter 8 itself and problem 21 should give you all the information you need to find the rook polynomial for that particular 'wrap-around 3-ply staircase chessboard'. Once you have that, you are done. Unfortunately I know of no place where the book is available for free.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the $n \times n$ matrix with entries $a_{ij} = 0$ if $i \in \{j-1,
j,j+1\}$ and $1$ otherwise.  Then your answer is the permanent of $A$.

For more, see [OEIS sequence A000183](https://oeis.org/A000183).